# cannot get response.entity message in $http error function

Tags: angularjs, http, jax-rs

i'm newbie in angularjs. i have developed a jax-rs restapi application that use filters to accept or reject basic authentication call
i have tested my application in postman and it works fine. i got error message if i don't pass user/pass for basic authentication or if they are wrong while everything is ok when user/pass are correct. i wrote an angularjs service that call the $http service passing in the header user/pass. if user/pass are ok the call response the right data while if the user/pass are wrong i got this error message

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

instead of the custom i wrote in the filter

```
Response unathourizedStatus = Response
        .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
        .entity("user cannot access the resource")
        .build();
requestContext.abortWith(unathourizedStatus);
```

this is my angular service

```
app.service("GeafimServiceBasicAuth", function($http, $base64) {
    var self = this;

    // Read all Registry Type
    self.getRegistryTypeBA = function(username, password) {

        console.log("service user " + username);
        console.log("service pass " + password);

        var auth = $base64.encode(username + ":" + password);
        // var headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + auth};

        console.log("service auth " + auth);


        var promise = $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : "webapi/basicauth/registrytype",
            headers : {
                "Authorization" : "Basic " + auth
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
        return promise;
    }
```

and this is the controller where i call the service

```
GeafimCtrlViewBA.$inject = [ "$http", "GeafimServiceBasicAuth" ];
function GeafimCtrlViewBA($http, GeafimServiceBasicAuth) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.error = false;
    vm.viewRegistryType = {};

    vm.getRegTypeBA = function(username, password) {
        // Get registry data using a Service with Basic Auth
        console.log("user " + username);
        console.log("pass " + password);
        GeafimServiceBasicAuth.getRegistryTypeBA(username, password).then(
                function(data) {
                    vm.viewRegistryType = data;
                }, function(err) {
                    console.log("error " + err)
                });
    }
```

when i write the console.log i would have the message i wrote in the entity and not the syntax error

how can i do that?

thanks

Comment: Show the raw response.

Comment: angular.min.js:103 GET http://localhost:8080/geafimrest/webapi/basicauth/registrytype 401 (Unauthorized)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:103n @ angular.min.js:99(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:96(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:131$eval @ angular.min.js:145$digest @ angular.min.js:142$apply @ angular.min.js:146(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:276Sf @ angular.min.js:37d @ angular.min.js:37
angular.min.js:118 SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at xc (angular.min.js:16)
    at dc (angular.min.js:91)
    at angular.min.js:92
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
    at gd (angular.min.js:92)
    at f (angular.min.js:94)
    at angular.min.js:131
    at m.$eval (angular.min.js:145)
    at m.$digest (angular.min.js:142)

Comment: I mean response, not error stack. Because error said that you're trying to parse non-json value.

Comment: yeap, i also tried to use this in my java code but didn't work      Response unathourizedStatus = Response
             .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
             .entity("user cannot access the resource")
             .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
             .build();
   requestContext.abortWith(unathourizedStatus);

Comment: in the Response message the entity is a string. how can i convert into json?

Comment: JSON is a specific format of string, maybe you don't have to convert it to JSON?

Answer (score 1):

The `$http` service is trying to `JSON.parse` the message and getting an error. Instead, specify the type as `"text/plain"`

```
Response unathourizedStatus = Response
    .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
    .type("text/plain")
    .entity("user cannot access the resource")
    .build();
requestContext.abortWith(unathourizedStatus);
```